# How to call local MVC 4 function inside ajax call

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, antiforgerytoken

In my SPA website i need to send antiforrgery token over to server by ajax. I use this article method:

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/preventing-cross-site-request-forgery-%28csrf%29-attacks

So in my layout.cshtml i have local function :

```
<script>
    @functions{
    public string TokenHeaderValue()
    {
        string cookieToken, formToken;
        AntiForgery.GetTokens(null, out cookieToken, out formToken);
        return cookieToken + ":" + formToken;                
    }
}
</script>
```

and i have separate js file named register.js where i call this function inside ajax:

```
   $.ajax({
                url: 'User/JsonRegister',
                type: "POST",
                data: d,
                headers: {
                    'RequestVerificationToken': '@TokenHeaderValue()'
                },
                success: function (result) {
                },
                error: function (result) {
                }
            });
```

the problem is that i never @TokenHeaderValue() is never called and i m keep getting this error:

```
The required anti-forgery form field "__RequestVerificationToken" is not present.
```

How do i solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i add token to my data this way: which solves problem

```
 AddAntiForgeryToken = function (data) {
            data.__RequestVerificationToken = $('#__AjaxAntiForgeryForm input[name=__RequestVerificationToken]').val();
            return data;
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is using server side helper function in the separate js file. If you need to have ajax call in the separate js file, set `@TokenHeaderValue()` value to a hidden field and read the value of hidden field in the js file.

Answer (score -1):

Pass data in JSON format

```
$.ajax({
     type:"POST",
     datatype:"JSON",
     data:{d:d}, // Remaining code is same

});
```

And use `[HttpPost]` before method signature in controller because it a `Post` request.